# Interpreting hex in a datasheet and converting using C bitwise left shift operators

Tags: c, hex, bit-manipulation

I'm reading a datasheet and it says that the size of the image can be determined by this:

> Image Length = len 0 + Len 1 * 100h + Len 2 * 10000h

And then the code implementing this on an mcu is

```
L0 = Buffer[5];
L1 = Buffer[6];
L2 = Buffer[7];

image_size = L0 + (L1 << 8) + (L2 << 16);
```

I was wondering if somebody could explain what is happening here? How do you go from one to the other? The mcu is 32-bit if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`100h` means 100 in hexadecimal notation which is 256 in decimal.

A multiplication of a number by 256 is equivalent of shifting its binary representation by 8 to the left.

Or more generally: the multiplication of a number by 2^n is equivalent of shifting its binary representation by n to the left. And a division of a number by 2^n is equivalent of shifting its binary representation by n to the right.

Example:

```
        2  * 256 = 512
000000010 <<   8 = 100000000    // << is the shift left operator
```

So actually this:

```
image_size = L0 + (L1 << 8) + (L2 << 16);
```

can be written as:

```
image_size = L0 + (L1 * 0x100) + (L2 * 0x10000);
```

The `0x` prefix means that the number is given in hexadecimal notation instead of decimal notation, so we can also write:

```
image_size = L0 + (L1 * 256) + (L2 * 65536);
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of your `L0`, `L1`, and `L2` as two-digit hexadecimal numbers `XX`, `YY`, and `ZZ`.

The situation here is that they're being put together to compose the six-digit hexadecimal number:

```
0xZZYYXX
```

So one way of putting them together, using only bitwise operators, would be `(L2 << 16) | (L1 << 8) | L0`, which we can visualize like this:

```
L0    ZZ         =    000000XX
L1    YY << 8    =    0000YY00
L2    ZZ << 16   =    00ZZ0000
                      --------
       bitwise OR:  0x00ZZYYXX
```

But as Michael Walz has explained, shifting left by 1 bit is equivalent to multiplying by 2, and shifting left by 8 bits is equivalent to multiplying by 256, or 0x100.  Furthermore, bitwise OR is very close to addition, and as long as there's no overflow, bitwise OR pretty much *is* addition.  So we get the same result as

```
(L2 * 0x10000) + (L1 * 0x100) + L0
```

If you're still having trouble seeing this, think about base 10 instead of base 16.  Suppose I wanted to "put together" the numbers 12, 34, and 56 to get 123456.  I'd do that by writing

```
(12 * 10000) + (34 * 100) + 56
```

Notice how the multipliers 10000 and 100 I used are eerily similar to `0x10000` and `0x100` in the hexadecimal example?

(Another way of thinking about these examples is that when you put `L0`, `L1`, and `L2` together you were working with a three-digit number in base 256, and when I put 12, 34, and 56 together I was working in base 100. But if you're not ready to think about base 100 and base 256 yet, don't worry, you don't have to.)